# Max-width on mobile (full-width div)

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a blue bar that runs along the top of my page that fills the full width of the screen, however, I can't get it to stick to a max-width.

On mobile it renders with an enormous amount of extra spacing on the right-hand side.

Any ideas?

You can see the code and CSS in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DavidMichaelangelo/4vj0gfp1/1/

HTML

```
<body>
                <div id="main-logo" class="clearfix">
                <div style="height: 26px; width: 174px; background-color: #000; color: #FFF;">Placeholder</div>
            </div>
            <div class="blue-line-headline clearfix">
                <div class="blue-line-content clearfix">
                    <span style="font-size:1.25em;">Open an Account and</span><br />
                    <span style="font-size:3em; font-weight: bold;">Save XX% for X months*</span>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.blue-line-headline {box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3); z-index: 15; color: #fff; width:100%; background-color:#1C3F94; padding: 0.5em 400%; margin: 0 -400%; max-width: 1100px;  display: block;}
.blue-line-content {padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px; margin: auto; width: 100%; position: relative; display: block;}
#main-logo {padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;}
```

Comment: Do you want it to extend across the whole page? Why don't you just use `width:100%` instead of assigning a max-width?

Comment: The issue is that I cannot get width: 100% to cause the bar to extend fully across the page (edge to edge). I used absolute positioning + hidden overflow on the body tag to accomplish it before but I need the bar to not be positioned absolutely because the content in it can change size and hide what is underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this

```
.blue-line-headline {box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3); z-index: 15; color: #fff; width:100%; background-color:#1C3F94; padding: 0.5em 400%; margin: 0 -400%; max-width: 1100px;  display: block;}
```

to

```
.blue-line-headline {box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);color: #fff; width:100%; background-color:#1C3F94;max-width: 1100px;}
```

Also, adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to blue-line-content will remove extra width from padding.

Comment: Thanks for helping Oshik but that didn't solve the program. I need the blue bar to extend all the way to the very edge on the left and right. My code accomplishes this, but it creates extra space that is rendered on mobile.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding what you are trying to achieve but isn't the extra space coming from padding? did you try adding box-sizing on the Div that you have padding values in?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4vj0gfp1/7/.
In CSS3 you can use the vw as unit. It stands for visual width.

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.blue-line-headline {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
    z-index: 15; 
    color: #fff; 
    width:100vw; 
    background-color:#1C3F94;
    padding: 0.5em 0; 
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 1100px;  
    display: block;}
.blue-line-content {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
#main-logo {padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;}
```

Comment: This seems to almost work, however, I need all the content to be positioned in the center. With this approach, everything is left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Bro try this and see.

If you want to determine whether its mobile, tab or pc use this code.

```
   /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) -----------
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- *
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pi
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio
/* Styles */
}
```

[Url of code](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)